# using LINQ to receive all data that have property active that is true

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

I am using MVC3 with EF model first.

I have this LINQ to receive all data:

```
        public List<CoreValueQuestion> GetAllCoreValueQuestions()
        {
            return db.Question.OfType<CoreValueQuestion>().OrderBy(x => x.QuestionText).ToList();
        }
```

My Question entity have a property that is bool and is called Active, I want to return all questions that have the active = true. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: return db.Question.OfType<CoreValueQuestion>().OrderBy(x => x.QuestionText).Where(x => x.Active == true).ToList();

Comment: Where should be before the `OrderBy` Think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.Question
     .OfType<CoreValueQuestion>()
     .Where(a=>a.Active==true)
     .OrderBy(x => x.QuestionText)
     .ToList();
```

Or if `Active` is not nullable column simply do this:

```
db.Question
     .OfType<CoreValueQuestion>()
     .Where(a=>a.Active)
     .OrderBy(x => x.QuestionText)
     .ToList();
```

Comment: He has not said if is a nullable field.

Comment: I should have used ´Where´ before ´OrderBy´ like asawyer said. Thank you both.

Comment: @asawyer: No problem. Updated the answer with your suggestion. Thanks for pointing that out